# Kubernetes Ingress controller Rewrite annotation

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed K8s Nginx ingress controller and configured ingress rules as per below Annotations and Path:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

path: /home(/|$)(.*)

Now, When I pass the URI as /home, the rewrite changes it to /home. So, the full URL becomes http://192.168.122.241/home and this works fine if I run the curl command as below:

```
~]# curl http://192.168.122.241/home
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

My question is that , the actual document root on the backend service(apache2) serving the content is located at "/". So, how the /home is being redirect to "/" ? Where is this redirection configured on the ingress-controller? I checked the nginx-ingress-controller nginx.conf file and can see the mentioned path regex, however not able to understand, how this is being worked to redirect to "/" on the backend service(apache)?

Answer (score 0):

rewrite-target change the behaviour of ingress, enabling us to modify the URL that hits the container.

Your case:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
path: /home(/|$)(.*)
(where: http://192.168.122.241/home,  /home becomes to this -> http://192.168.122.241/home)*No changes in the path

Answering your question:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
path: /home
(where: http://192.168.122.241/home , /home becomes to this -> /)

According to my understood, this rewrite target path, allows in the server handle the request path hitting the container with the next examples
/get
/post
/delete

if we are not using rewrite in our services we should handle the request as:
/home/get
/home/post
/home/delete

rewrite-target=changing the URL that hits your container